# ERROR at line 0: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

[image]

hi everyone  please  help me  to resolve  this  problem, i dunno how to fix  it, although it had  changed  the code  but  the  same error still appear !!

Comment: do you have a type created called `adresse`?

Comment: Please don't add text as images.

Comment: Besides adresse, since you're defining a custom type as object, then you also need constructor functions, in order to instantiate the object.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code I see TWO errors in `USER_ERRORS`. The first is

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'ADRESSE' must be declared
```

The second is

```
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
```

I suggest that the type `ADRESSE` needs to be defined before compiling `taleb`.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8bc39e/1)

Best of luck.